# What exactly needs to be included in a RubyMine custom Ruby configuration, esp. for debugging?

Tags: configuration, interpreter, rubymine

I usually use rvm, but also need to work with a custom Ruby build. I understand that when I go to the RubyMine "Settings", "Languages & Frameworks", "Ruby SDK and Gems" dialog, I need to press "+" and select "New Local with Custom Configurator".

On that dialog, the Ruby interpreter path is self explanatory, but I don't know which environment variables I need to specify in the "Custom Configurator" session. What information needs to go there?

[image: custom configuration dialog]

I am using RubyMine 2021.1 on both Mac OS and Linux. I need to be able to debug, which means that when RubyMine installs the debug support gems, they need to go to the right location, and be found from that location.

Comment: You can also check the corresponding documentation topic: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/configuring-language-interpreter.html#add_local_configurator

Comment: I had been to that page, but it didn't tell me what environment variables needed to be specified. Also, I was unfamiliar with the `env` command and had to look up how to specify multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that all I needed to specify there was my GEM_HOME:

`env GEM_HOME=/opt/my-custom-ruby/gems/2.7.0`

I was surprised that I didn't also need to explicitly set the path to the directory containing the Ruby interpreter (for commands *other than* `ruby`, such as `bundle`), but I guess RubyMine does that for me. Or, maybe it doesn't, and I just haven't encountered an error yet.

---

Edit: It turns out I *did* have an issue with a gem not being found. I added to that env command and the problem went away, but I'm not really sure yet if that was the issue or if adding both `GEM_PATH` and `PATH` were necessary. Here is what I wound up with:

`env GEM_HOME=/opt/my-custom-ruby/gems/2.7.0 GEM_PATH=/opt/my-custom-ruby/gems/2.7.0  PATH=/opt/my-custom-ruby/bin/ruby:$PATH`

---

EDIT 2021-12-24

I just tried this again on a new installation and the above did not work. I was getting build errors saying that I needed to install the development tools. It turned out that when specifying the path in the
Custom Configurator field I needed to include the path for the gcc compiler. I just put most of the paths in my login PATH value there, and the gem installation succeeded.